# Overriding View model to sanitize string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antixsslibrary

I have created a model binder to sanitize string property from malicious input using `AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode` for us to be able to save encoded string without worrying about XSS. So I have made this work, however, the only problem that I'm having and solving is how to Decode string property with AntiXss encoded the value.

The page render this text as see the below:

[image]

I want the page to render the text to `<test> me` instead of the above image. I tried to look to some resource to do this and can make this happen by adding an extension method to a string in the view. But this is tedious I want to set something global that automatically sanitize string properties in the model before rendering them on the page.

Could anyone suggest a way implement auto string sanitization globally or override the view model and check for string properties and sanitize them before rendering the page?

**Update:**
Or a way which I could override this part of `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your code isn't decoding it will depend on how you are implementing your model binder.

To decode you would normally just use `HttpUtility.Decode`, so you may have to run this somewhere.

It may be that you need to put the `[AllowHtml]` attribute onto your model properties.

Alternatively it may be that you need to implement `IHtmlString` somehow to make use of the `ToHtmlString()` method which lets you put html directly onto the page without MVC sanitising it automatically.

Possibly some more code would make it clearer but one of those three should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Our Implementation of model binder just encode the string properties, what I want to achieve is to globally decode string properties in a model before rendering them on the page. I know I could use your three given solutions but It would mean that I have to define those to each property which I'm avoiding.

Comment: I can't find a way of globally doing this other than either defining all your strings as `IHtmlString` or by somehow overriding the razor view engine. I couldn't find an implementation of the actual rendering part (I suspect it will be horribly complicated). It is possible to put an attribute on your Action (or define a global attribute) to decode strings as part of the model binding, take a look at this https://github.com/CypressNorth/.NET-WebApi-HttpStringDecodeFilter

Comment: I have seen that. I was about to try that. Let see how this progress using that technique. Thanks